# tqdm.notebook horizontal alignment of multiple bars

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, tqdm

I'd like to know if there is a way to align multiple progress bars in a Jupyter notebook, like they look [in the docs](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#ipythonjupyter-integration).

By contrast, my experience is that the horizontal position of the bar varies through the iterations (as the progress percentage changes) and based on the width of the description.

For example, just trying the snippet from the docs:

```py
from tqdm.notebook import trange, tqdm
from time import sleep

for i in trange(3, desc='1st loop'):
    for j in tqdm(range(100), desc='2nd loop'):
        sleep(0.01)
```

What I get is unaligned bars:

[image]

Instead, in the docs all the bars are neatly aligned, no matter the description width (in pixels) or the current percentage through the iteration:

[image]

(However, note the slight differences of import between the image in the docs and the code snippet they give; for example, `tqdm.tnrange` is deprecated).

I tried using `bar_format` e.g. with `'{desc:<20}{percentage:3.0f}%|{bar}{r_bar}'` or using `{l_bar:>20}...`, but no luck so far.

Versions:

```
ipython=8.15.0
ipywidgets=8.0.4
jupyter_client=8.1.0
jupyterlab=4.0.6
jupyterlab_widgets=3.0.9
python=3.11.5
tqdm=4.65.0
```